# Pitfalls of a variable size array in C

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, variable-length-array

The following snippet compiles properly using standard `gcc`. What are possible pitfalls here? *--especially for kernel level development*.

```
int n;

f(){n=2;}
g(){int b[n];}

main(){
        int a[n];
        f();
        g();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile (`2 : error: variably modified 'c' at file scope`).

Comment: n is 0 at compile time and int c[n] will be a zero length array because structures are resolved at compile time.

Comment: Since kernel structs often have to outlive the calls that raise them, there would seem to be limited usefulness, even if allocated on a kernel stack, (of limited size anyway).  Of couse, a global VLA does not make sense, (or compile), anyway:(

Comment: These are no standard compliant function definitions. They will _not_ compiler without warning with gcc 5.1+

Answer (score 5):

It is invalid code because variable length arrays may not have sizes equal to 0. In your example, file-scope variable `n` is initialized by 0.

This array

```
    int a[n];
```

has zero size because variable `n` was zero initialized as having static storage duration.

To get a valid program you should write something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n;

void f( void ){n=2;}
void g( void ){int b[n]; printf( "sizeof( b ) = %zu\n", sizeof( b ) ); }

int main( void )
{
        f();
        int a[n];
        printf( "sizeof( a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );
        g();
}
```

Take into account that VLA(s) were introduced in C99 and at the same time the Standard suppressed the default return type `int` of functions.

Comment: Who is so clever that down voted the answer?

Comment: @Ali Abbasinasab  Is it you who down voted?

Comment: Why did u remove my answer? And why did you deactivate my account? Interesting personality!

Comment: @Ali Abbasinasab I hear this the first time. I have nothing common with the removing of your answer and deactivating your account. It is not me.